# [US20160122959]

Tags: patent-infringement, legal-status

In reference to the patent: [US20160122959](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160122959)

What is the status of this ? I have a similar design and have started to make these and was looking to get patent for it... but what to make sure i'm not coping it... i have not seen this device on the market and want to start selling them . please let me know .

Answer (score 1):

It is an application that may become a granted patent. It is not yet possible to tell exactly what scope the protection will have.

Answer (score 0):

As DonQuiKing says, this is an application not yet a patent. The claims very likely will change. What you need to do is carefully read the claims and see if your product infringes. To infringe, you need to do every aspect of a claim. The first claim is the only independent claim so look at that first.

> 1. A snow plow blade attachment and mounting for use with an existing plow blade mold board with a set of holes, comprising: a traditional
>      cutting blade with a hole pattern and with a bottom part; a
>      reinforcing plate with the hole pattern; and a rounded cutting edge
>      snow plow blade attachment having an upper flat section with
>      pre-drilled holes that match the hole pattern to receive the
>      reinforcing plate on one side and the traditional cutting blade on the
>      other side, and a lower curved section with a 180 degree radius that
>      protrudes forward of the upper flat section on the one side, said
>      rounded cutting edge snow plow blade attachment being secured to the
>      existing plow blade mold board by fastening means passing through the
>      pre-drilled holes and the holes in the existing plow blade mold board
>      and the hole pattern of the reinforcing plate such that the lower
>      curved section protrudes forward of the existing plow blade mold board
>      on the one side, with the lower curved section engaging the surface to
>      be plowed by falling below the bottom part of the traditional cutting
>      blade.

If your product doesn't do all of that, you may be OK. Again, the claims may change and get narrower. I would suggest consulting with a patent attorney.